# die() if no matches found in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to send a die() command if SELECT can't find matches in MYSQL. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
<?php     
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 

$getcode = trim($_GET['code']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Jinn_waitlist WHERE code LIKE '%" . $getcode . "%'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$position = $row['id']; }

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use mysqli_num_rows()

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) <=0){
     die('exited');
}
```

See doc: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Advice: I suggest you start learning the OOP way of connecting to a DB, instead of the procedural you are doing now.
Plus search and learn about MySQL injections.

Comment: You forgot ";" after die('exited'). But even with it I get this error _Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result_

Comment: Sorry I'm answering from my phone... Use $result not $sql in your case.

Comment: Maybe you could help me one more time.. In my MYSQL DB I've got a column 'code' which is varchar(500) for example '9RQ66YudG8202Kbkk6738' I am doing something wrong, because without '%" in the PHP code I can't find a match in my DB. Even using phpmyadmin. But using '%" . $getcode . "%' is not secure. Maybe you know what I am doing wrong? I am passing this 'code' as a GET like this $_GET['code']

Comment: If the code is specific why are you using LIKE instead of = $getcode?

Comment: Because it returns 0 rows.. maybe this is because I've uploaded data from the txt file with tabs? Usign this code: $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'keys.txt' INTO TABLE Jinn_waitlist";

Comment: Do you see the field content in MySQL app (SequelPro, phpmyadmin or whatever you use)?

Comment: Yes, all the data is in my MySQL. I use phpmyadmin. Even if I search with phpmyadmin I only can find the match using "SELECT * FROM Jinn_waitlist WHERE code LIKE '%" . $getcode . "%'" . My 'code' is mixed numbers, letters and capitals like 168GS31LpeU7856YidK5798

Comment: Ok, try looking for ... code = ".trim($getcode)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli_query returns an mysqli_result

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

From there you have the row count ($result->num_rows)